# Programming language decision for C++ legacy project workflow

Tags: java, python, programming-languages, binding, java-native-interface

I have quite a lot of C++ legacy code modules from my colleagues, unfortunately poorly written. Each is doing a different job, but they are  all GNU C++ code running under Linux.

I want to write a controller program, to make a singular C++ module for a workflow, for a very urgent demo. Also I need to write a front-end web-app allowing clients submitting jobs to the controller.

My main criteria are:

- development speed (very urgent demo)
- good binding with C++ (I have legacy code I do not want to rewrite in another language)
- smooth introduction of new programming language to team (has some python, java and perl knowledge)

**What programming language fits my needs best, and why?**

Details:

I lean towards python for its perfect binding with C++, as writing JNI is too much work, and kind of obsolete nowadays. However, no one in my team is Python programmer; I do know some Python (no experience in server side programming at all). I have been developing Java EE apps last year, but I do not think JNI is a good solution. Only one team member knows some Perl, others are pure C++ programmers.

Comment: If you use SWIG to generate language bindings, the language choice should not be an issue, as it supports Python, Perl, Java, etc. See http://www.swig.org/compat.html#SupportedLanguages

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am too used to my own vocabulary ;-). 
Cauz' => because

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting the "very urgent demo" part, assuming that that would take about a month, depending on the complexity, I'd stick to the familiar.
True, maintaining python would be easier in the end, and learning python should be a breeze, if you deem it viable.

I'd say, have the team learn python and do the basic stuff, as you learn the deeper parts, you could build classes for them to extend/implement. That way, you get things done as they learn.

Answer (score 2):

Given the urgency, I'd have to stick with C++.

Without that, I'd say keep what you got, but feel free to switch to a preferred language when refactoring. That would be the time to do it.

What you should **not** do, ever, is "port" anything to another language without rewriting or changing functionality in any way. It is a total waste of time, when the "best" outcome you can hope for is that it has no new bugs when you are done.

Comment: In addition, since the other programmers know C++, you can pull them in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python. You could write very basic wrappers using the Python C API and then call said functions from Python with relative ease.